# Creating fast search results for data in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have stored 100000+ items in a DynamoDB table (key-value). I want to offer the user the functionality to enter a search word and find items in this table that matches the search word. What is a good way to achieve this under 3 seconds? I have a few ideas, but I would like to validate them with the community, my favourite approach would be to:

1. Scan the dynamo DB every hour and store the items as JSON in a separate dynamoDB table with only 1 key.
   (This way I don't have to scan all items every time a user performs a search)
2. Anytime the user searches, send a get request to a lambda function that fetches the items JSON from the separate dynamoDB table.
   (Warning: this can be problematic with 100000+ items, large size and will take time)
3. Lambda function receives all items in JSON and runs them through a search algorithm.
4. Lambda function produces a list (sorted by relevance) of items to respond to the user (i.e. the search results).

There are 2 major problems with this approach that makes me think that DynamoDB is the wrong tool for this task:

1. DynamoDB cannot store JSON larger than 400KB.
2. The time it takes for the lambda function to fetch a 100000+ item JSON from a dynamoDB table.

Other solutions I am considering includes caching and Elasticsearch. Are there any consensus on what a good way to perform this is?

**Edit 1**

Also considering storing the JSON in S3 because there is no file size limit and that it is rumoured that it is faster for lambda to fetch data from S3 than from a query with key from DynamoDB (?)

**Edit 2**

I am also considering storing the data as persistent variables in the lambda function, although, I am not so sure how this would work exactly. Is this even possible?

Comment: Elasticsearch isn't a bad option, especially if you want fulltext search. Dynamodb supports streaming directly to elasticsearch. Dynamodb scans can be expensive in terms of cost.

Comment: If you store in S3, you can use athena to query the data, but that's not going to be a fast response time

Comment: On your comment "it is rumoured that it is faster for lambda to fetch data from S3 than from a query with key from DynamoDB", I think it's highly unlikely that S3 would be close in performance to DynamoDB query, unless perhaps you're talking about lots of items being returned by the query and the resultset was pre-populated in a single, small S3 object so you can do a simple GetObject.

Comment: On the topic of searching, you can't use DynamoDB as a general purpose search engine. If you can tightly control your search queries and terms in advance, then maybe DynamoDB would fit, but not if you want arbitrary search capability.

Comment: If you have experience with it, ElasticSearch is excellent. For a more out of the box solution you could also consider [AWS CloudSearch ](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/).

Comment: There are many ways you can do it but first do you have to use DynamoDB? If you are using DynamoDB because it has a free tier then skip it altogether if you need to provide search functionality. It is ideal for use cases where you are just storing and retrieving user-specific data.